# VBA - check if file exist without knowing extension

Tags: excel, vba, search

I have an excel workbook with column [A] having numerous filenames. But only the name of the file, so without any extension. I would like to loop through each cell and check whether a file in a specific folder exist matching this string in the cell.

someone did not manage to find anything on Google.

thanks

Comment: "someone did not manage to find anything on Google" and indeed someone is now asking someone to do their work for them. This is really a site to help fix or upgrade code, not to create it from scratch, that would be a job. Saying that, I would say your query while possible to do, is ultimately incorrect, the folder could have 'File.jpg', 'File.ai', 'File.doc', 'File.xlsx' and all would be valid hits but could return a false positive if you don't know the extension you are looking for i.e. 'File.png'. A file called 'File' exists so would return true, but no file called 'File.png' is there.

Comment: autocorrect: somehow, not someone. my idea is to manipulate the string at the for each file in folder part in a way that from the right I remove everything until the first '.' and then everything after a '\' appears.

Comment: regarding your concern with different extensions. there only one filename with an unknown extension, but not more than 1

Comment: @smartini, I am pretty sure my code works. I didn't know what you wanted to do if you found it, but this answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
Const dirPath As String = "C:\whateveryourPathIs\"

Sub RunIt()
    Dim Rcell As Range
    For Each Rcell In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Cells

        If Not IsEmpty(Rcell) Then

            If CheckIfFileExists(dirPath, Rcell.Value) Then
                'whatever you want to happen when it finds a match
                Debug.Print Rcell.Value & " was found"

            End If
        End If

    Next Rcell

End Sub



Private Function CheckIfFileExists(srchDIR As String, MatchMember As String) As Boolean
    Dim file As Variant, nameOfFile As String

    If Right(srchDIR, 1) <> "\" Then srchDIR = srchDIR & "\"

    file = Dir(srchDIR)
    While (file <> "")

        nameOfFile = Left(file, InStrRev(file, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)


        If UCase(nameOfFile) = UCase(MatchMember) Then
            CheckIfFileExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If

        file = Dir
    Wend
End Function
```

Comment: thanks. this InStr search will also find files named "test13", but I search for "test1" e.g.

Comment: your code works as well, thanks for your update effort. user can use both codes now.

Comment: Thanks @smartini. I'm not sure what your code is aiming to do, but your `for i loop` doesn't have an `i` in it, so it's just spinning redundantly. Additionally, it doesn't look like it's using the correct function. If you're using the `right` function and testing if it'll <> "." that's only going to be the first instance. No loop needed. Perhaps you mean the `mid` function? I'm not sure, but I appreciate the tick. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

@PGCodeRider Thanks, I modified your code to my needs and it works now. anyone who is interested ("or also did not find anything on google") below the code:

```
Const dirPath As String = "C:\folderpath\..."

Sub RunIt()
    Dim Rcell As Range
    For Each Rcell In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Cells

        If Not IsEmpty(Rcell) Then

            If CheckIfFileExists(dirPath, Rcell.Value) Then
                'whatever you want to happen when it finds a match
                Debug.Print Rcell.Value & " was found"

            End If
        End If

    Next Rcell

End Sub

Private Function CheckIfFileExists(srchDIR As String, MatchMember As String) As Boolean
    Dim file As Variant
    Dim length As Long

    If Right(srchDIR, 1) <> "\" Then srchDIR = srchDIR & "\"

        file = Dir(srchDIR)

        While (file <> "")

            length = Len(file)
                For i = 1 To length
                    If Right(file, 1) <> "." Then
                        file = Left(file, length - 1)
                        length = Len(file)
                    Else
                    Exit For
                    End If
                Next i

            file = Left(file, length - 1)

        'If InStr(1, file, MatchMember, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            If file = MatchMember Then
                CheckIfFileExists = True
                Exit Function
            End If
            file = Dir
        Wend
End Function
```

Comment: As my other comment said... your `for i loop` has some problems. No `i` in the loop and I think you mean `mid` not `Right`.

Comment: thanks for the hint. indeed the for i loop makes no sense, i rather meant do while (I only wanted to limit the loop in as much as it has a max loop like the length of the string). the purpose of thise Right() function is that i only want to erase  the file extension from the string. - it works. but I know, it is not well writting code though.

Comment: your edit makes no sense it the program does not what it should do. did you try to run it? look into the debut.print windows please, you'll see that a loop is nessassary.

Comment: Now I see what you're doing. That's excessive and inefficient (welcome to SO!! ☠) I'll append a correction to your code, without touching yours, so you can see the difference. I don't think your answer provides anything that mine doesn't, but I enjoy a healthy discussion. You look like you're just getting your feet wet with VBA and I admire your creative approach. We've all been there.

Comment: not quite new to VBA, but this time I was a little rusty. Appreciate your help though!